Beta decay and maximum beta energy in https://atom.kaeri.re.kr
According to:
https://atom.kaeri.re.kr/cgi-bin/decay?Cs-137%20B-,
in the beta- decay of Cs-137 to Ba-137, there are 2 likely scenarios:

only one electron is emitted.
an electron is emitted and the nucleus ends up in an exited state where it decays by gamma-ray emission.

The mass defect converted to energy gives (almost) exactly 1.1756 MeV.
So I assume that the Max.E(keV) of 1176 keV given in kaeri is the maximum TOTAL energy of the beta ray (with the mass of the electron included) when the nucleus goes through path 1).
And the Max.E(keV) of 514 keV is the maximum TOTAL energy of the beta ray when the nucleus goes through path 2). So this means that the electron only carries a maximum kinetic energy of about 3 keV.
So what does the Avg.E(keV) 174 keV mean?
What am I getting wrong?

When you look up the masses of the Cs-137 and Ba-137 atoms the mass given is the nucleus plus the electrons in the atom. So the 136.907089 amu mass given for the Cs atom includes 55 electrons, but the 136.9058272amu mass given for the Ba atom includes 56 electrons. This means when you calculate the mass deficit of 1.175 MeV by subtracting the atomic masses you are out by the mass of one electron.
The energies given in your link are just the kinetic energies, not the KE plus the 0.511 MeV rest mass of the electron, and that's why for the two step decay the average makes sense.

You are right!
I did not pay attention and thought I was using the masses of the nuclei.
I don't know how you could unravel the mess in my head, spot the error, and express the answer so succinctly!

@Juan Because I have made exactly the same mistake myself! :-)

There are three decay modes although only two are shown in the diagram because one of them occurs only rarely.

Using the data in the diagram:

beta (max) 1.1756 MeV
beta (max) 0.8921 MeV + gamma 0.2835 Mev - rare
beta (max) 0.5139 MeV + gamma 0.6617 MeV - most common - path 2

The energy of a beta ranges from zero to the maximum shown above and the average is somewhere in between these two values.
Thus path 2 betas range from zero to (1.1756 - 0.6617=) 0.5139 MeV with an average value of 0.174 MeV.
When doing the calculations atomic masses are used.
$\underbrace{^{137}_{\,\,55}\rm Cs}_\text{55p + 82n+55e}\to \underbrace{^{137}_{\,\,56}\rm Ba^+}_\text{56p+81n+55e} + \underbrace{\beta^-}_\text{1e} +\bar \nu$
Thus when doing the calculations the mass of the neutral $\underbrace{^{137}_{\,\,56}\rm Ba}_\text{56p+81n+56e}$ atom is used which includes the beta as a Barium $\underbrace{^{137}_{\,\,56}\rm Ba^+}_\text{56p+81n+55e}$ ion is produced in the decay..

Thank you for your answer! You are right, I didn't realize I was using the atomic masses.
